# Projection of set of 3D points into virtual image plane in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

Anyone know how to project set of 3D points into virtual image plane in opencv c++
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have your transformation matrix defined (rotation, translation, etc) to map the 3D space to the 2D virtual image plane, then just multiply your 3D point coordinates (x, y, z) to the matrix to get the 2D coordinates in the image.

Comment: Hi, I am working with the kinect.I had calibrated the both cameras and now I have rotational matrix ,translation vector of depth camera with respect to rgb camera.I have to map depth pixels to rgb pixels.I took depth 2D point and projected into 3d space and  I transformed these 3D ponts into rgb 3D projection using the R,T matrices.Now can you please tell me how can I project these 3D points into rgb image pixels.  thank you

Comment: @user3004528 if you use kinect with opencv, try considering to use highgui functions such as retrieve and so on. And there is a option called registration which is on by default and makes exactly what you want.
Here the doc: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_highgui.html

Answer (score 0):

registration (OpenNI 2) or alternative viewPoint capability (openNI 1.5) indeed help to align depth with rgb using a single line of code. The price you pay is that you cannot really restore exact X, Y point locations in 3D space since the row and col are moved after alignment.

Sometimes you need not only Z but also X, Y and want them to be exact; plus you want the alignment of depth and rgb. Then you have to align rgb to depth. Note that this alignment is not supported by Kinect/OpenNI. The price you pay for this - there is no RGB values in the locations where depth is undefined.

If one knows extrinsic parameters that is rotation and translation of the depth camera relative to color one then alignment is just a matter of making an alternative viewpoint: restore 3D from depth, and then look at your point cloud from the point of view of a color camera: that is apply inverse rotation and translation. For example, moving camera to the right is like moving the world (points) to the left. Reproject 3D into 2D and interpolate if needed. This is really easy and is just an inverse of 3d reconstruction; below, Cx is close to w/2 and Cy to h/2;

col = focal*X/Z+Cx
row = -focal*Y/Z+Cy // this is because row in the image increases downward

A proper but also more expensive way to get a nice depth map after point cloud rotation is to trace rays from each pixel till it intersects the point cloud or come sufficiently close to one of the points. In this way you will have less holes in your depth map due to sampling artifacts.